# WANを経由したSocket通信（TCP/UDP）について

Tags: linux, network

以下のような構成で同一LANでの通信のように、PC1でacceptしているところを
PC2、PC3からconnectしてsocket通信を行いたいのですが、ルーター1でNAT越えの
設定をしてやれば、クライアント側からルーター1のグローバルIP／設定したポートを指定して
やれば通信できるものなのでしょうか？
ダメな場合、どうすれば以下の構成でSocket通信が可能かご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

■ネットワーク構成

```
サーバー側                     クライアント側
==========================================
PC1 -- ルーター1 -- WAN -- ルーター2 -- PC2
         LAN1 -|    |      |-LAN2
                    |
                    └------ルーター3 -- PC3
                           | LAN3
```

Comment: `ルーター1`の機能次第なので、マニュアルを見るか具体的な機種名を上げて回答を募るかだと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。機能次第というのはどういうことでしょうか。NAT以外になにか必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: NAT（[正確にはNAPT](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B#NAT%E3%81%A8NAPT)）は内側から外側に出ていくことしかできません。`accept`するためにはDMZやUPnPなど別の機能が必要です。

Comment: NATはルーター1で設定するもので外部から特定のポート番号でアクセスしてきたものをLAN内の任意のIPのPCへと流すものだと思っていましたが違いましたでしょうか。。私はいろいろ勘違いしていそうですね。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NATはルーター1で設定するもので外部から特定のポート番号でアクセスしてきたものをLAN内の任意のIPのPCへと流すものだと思っていました

[NATとNAPT](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B#NAT%E3%81%A8NAPT)で次のように説明されています。

> 元来のNATは、送受信するパケット上のIPアドレスだけを識別して変換するものであるため、複数のホストから同時にローカル外のネットワークに接続しようとすると、ローカルのホスト数と同数のグローバルアドレスが必要になる。NAPTでは、IPアドレスに加えてポート番号の識別や変換をすることで、複数のホストからローカル外のネットワークに接続する際、異なるローカルアドレスを同一のグローバルアドレス配下の異なるポートとして表現し、必要なグローバルアドレスの数を減らすことができる。 動的NAPTは、インターネットプロバイダから利用者に対するグローバルIPアドレスの割り当て等でよく用いられる。

質問文で**NAT**と触れられていますが、文面から**動的NAPT**であり、元来のNATではないと判断します。
元来のNATであれば言及されているように外部からのアクセスはそのまま内部アドレスに変換されて中継されますが、動的NAPTではそれができません。

コメントでも言及しましたが、ルーター1に[**DMZ**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%9E%E6%AD%A6%E8%A3%85%E5%9C%B0%E5%B8%AF_(%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3))の機能があれば、外部からのアクセスを全てPC1へ中継することができ質問のネットワークを構築することができます。また[**UPnP IGD**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)の機能があり、PC1のアプリケーションがルーター1にポート割り当てを要求する場合、ルーター1は割り当てたポートのみPC1へ中継します。

質問の前提条件とは多少異なりますが、インターネットサービスプロバイダーを２つ契約し、PC1にグローバルIPを割り当ててしまう方法もあります。

いずれにせよ、既にコメントした通り、ルーター1にどのような機能があるかに依存します。

Comment: 詳細ありがとうございます。大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

基本は可能。気になるのは

- ルータ１とルータ2、3の間の宛先どうやって管理するの？
  　→グローバルIP使うの？DDNS使うの？
- こんなにさらして大丈夫？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

宛先はまずまずの試験的にはグローバルIPを調べて都度設定と考えています。都度調べて変更、ということをせずに繋げるためには固定グローバルIPにするかDDNSを使うかが必要でしょうか。

さらしてというのは構成のことでしょうか？特別問題になるような内容とも思いませんが、具体的にどこを気にしていらっしゃるのでしょうか。不勉強で申し訳ありませんが、私が気づいていない問題があるのであれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: ごめんなさい。セキュリティ機器がまったくなかったので（ルータのFWたのみでしょうかね。）、直つなぎなのかと認識しました。なので、「さらして」という表現です。別に現状書いている情報はなんてことはないです。
このPC間ではなにをやるんでしょうか？
そして、都度設定変更することなしにつなぐためには、固定IPかDDNSが選択子だと思います。

Comment: そういう意味でしたか。勘違い失礼しました。
また、ご教示ありがとうございます。
ネットワーク関連はどうも苦手でして。なんとなくイメージはわかるのですが、具体的にどうすればというのがよくわかっていないのでもっと勉強しなければいけませんね。